# When not to use huge

Tags: word-choice

I know that huge means very large. However, I have heard from my English friends that huge cannot be used instead of very large in some situations. What are some examples where huge cannot be used instead of very large or very big?

Comment: A huge city (usage examples) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20huge%20city%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2014,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: Is there any situation where huge cannot be used instead of very large? @user66974

Comment: I will edit the question @Greybeard

Comment: See [huge or large. Which one should I use?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/) as asked n English Language Learners. It's probably useful to note that it's not idiomatic to attach "quantifiers" (such as ***very, rather***) to ***huge***, which *always* implies *"**surprisingly** large"*. Hence you *can't* naturally say *London is an **extremely huge** city*, for example.

Comment: 'Very large' is a semi-standard variant of 'extra large' when sizing men[']s clothing. 'Huge' isn't.